# Spring Social for Android Facebook development

Tags: java, android, facebook, spring-social

I am trying to integrate Spring Social for Android in a non maven application. Can anyone help me by pointing up the complete list of jar files that i require to integrate this into my Android application ? Doing this by trial and error is getting quite cumbersome, as i have to match various jar files with their respective versions ?

Answer (score 1):

take a look on http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.social/spring-social-core/1.0.3.RELEASE

This artifact depends on ...

```
Group   Artifact    Version
org.apache.httpcomponents   httpclient  4.2.3
org.springframework.security    spring-security-crypto  3.1.3.RELEASE
org.springframework spring-jdbc 3.1.4.RELEASE
org.springframework spring-web  3.1.4.RELEASE
```

you may manually build (recursively looking into all depencencies) dependency list and download all required jars

Comment: Thanks. I did it this way, in the end. You would think Spring would provide a concurrent package for MAVEN/GRADLE builds

Comment: hmm, if you are using gradle in your android projects - try to switch to gradle tab on http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.social/spring-social-core/1.0.3.RELEASE, where you'll see 'org.springframework.social:spring-social-core:1.0.3.RELEASE' which you can add into your build.gradle file in dependencies section, see also  http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/dependency_management.html